# How to test a component with callback function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component like this:

```js
    export const MyList = props => {

      const myCallbackFunction = () => {
        // do stuff
      };

      const ListEmptyComponent = (
        <MyCustomComponent
            text="sample text"
            onButtonPress={myCallbackFunction}
        />
      );

      return (
        <FlatList
         data={DATA}
         renderItem={({ item }) => (<Item title={item.title} />)}
         ListEmptyComponent={ListEmptyComponent} />
       );
    };
```

I want to test the ListEmptyComponent. Inside my test I try to mock `myCallbackFunction` and make sure `ListEmptyComponent` is equal to `MyCustomComponent`:

```js
    it("should display the MyCustomComponent", () => {
        const myCallbackFunction = jest.fn();
        const component = renderComponent();

        expect(
            component
                .find(FlatList)
                .prop("ListEmptyComponent")
        ).toEqual(
            <MyCustomComponent
                text="sample text"
                onButtonPress={myCallbackFunction}
            />
        );
    });
```

The test fails because this is what it expects:
`onButtonPress={[Function mockConstructor]}`
and this is what it receives:`onButtonPress={[Function myCallbackFunction]}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to `myCallbackFunction` the component use is not something you pass from props, so you might consider to change the component to use `onButtonPress={props.myCallbackFunction}`

Answer (score 2):

As the code is defined, the function `myCallbackFunction` is a private function, so you are not going to be able to mock it.

In your test, you are defining a mock function with the same name of the private function, but that does not mean they are the same function (they are not).

Without changing the component code, you could check that the component `ListEmptyComponent` receives a function in the `onButtonPress` property:

```
it("should display the MyCustomComponent", () => {
    const myCallbackFunction = jest.fn();
    const component = renderComponent();

    expect(
        component
            .find(FlatList)
            .prop("ListEmptyComponent")
    ).toEqual(
        <MyCustomComponent
            text="sample text"
            onButtonPress={expect.any(Function)}
        />
    );
});
```

Comment: @mgarica Thank you very much. It worked. The only issue that I get a warning that says:
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `myCallbackFunction` of type `object` supplied to `MyCustomComponent `, expected `function`.
        in MyCustomComponent
Not sure why cuz I'm passing a function which is what it should expect